# HTML5, Easel.js game problems

Tags: html, easeljs

Been working on an easel game tutorial that involves an animated character going across the screen and avoiding crates falling from above. I've followed the code in the tutorial exactly but no joy;nothing seems to be loading (including images which are mapped correctly). No errors regarding syntax seem to occur so not sure what the problem is. It's a fair bit of code so totally understand if no-one has the time but just in case here it is ;

Site Page code (ill post the individual JavaScript file codes if anyone is interested;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> 
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>

<script src="lib/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/Platform.js"></script>
<script src="JS/Hero.js"></script>
<script src="JS/Crate.js"></script>

<script>
var KEYCODE_SPACE = 32, KEYCODE_LEFT = 37, KEYCODE_RIGHT = 39;
var canvas, stage, lfheld, rtheld, platforms, crates, hero, heroCenter, key, door, gameTxt;

var keyDn = false, play=true, dir="right";
var loaded = 0, vy = 0, vx = 0;
var jumping = false, inAir = true, gravity = 2;

var img = new Image();
var bgimg = new Image();
var kimg = new Image();
var dimg = new Image();

var platformW = [300, 100, 180, 260, 260, 100, 100];
var platformX = [40, 220, 320, 580, 700, 760, 760];
var platformY = [460, 380, 300, 250, 550, 350, 450];
document.onkeydown=handleKeyDown;
document.onkeyup=handleKeyUp;

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    bgimg.onload = this.handleImageLoad;

    bgimg.src = "img/scene.jpg";

kimg.onload = this.handleImageLoad;

kimg.src="img/key.png";

dimg.onload = this.handleImageLoad;

dimg.src = "img/door.jpg";

img.onload = this.handleImageLoad;

img.src = "img/hero.png";
}

function handleImageLoad(event) {
    loaded+=1;
    if (loaded==4){
        start();
    }
}

function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if(!e){ var e = window.event; }
    switch(e.keycode) {
        case KEYCODE_LEFT: lfHeld = true;
dir="left"; break;
case KEYCODE_RIGHT: rtHeld = true;
dir="right"; break;
case KEYCODE_SPACE: jump(); break;
    }
}


function handleKeyUp(e) {
    if(!e){ var e = window.event; }
    switch(e.keycode) {
        case KEYCODE_LEFT: lfHeld = false;
keyDn=false; hero.gotoAndStop("idle_h"); break;
case KEYCODE_RIGHT: rtHeld = false;
keyDn=false; hero.gotoAndStop("idle"); break;
    }
}




function start(){
    var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(bgimg);
    stage.addChild(bg);
    door = new createjs.Bitmap(dimg);
    door.x = 131;
    door.y = 384;
    stage.addChild(door);
    hero = new Hero(img);
    hero.x = 80;
    hero.y = 450;
    stage.addChild(Hero);

    crates = new Array();
    paltforms = new Array();
    for(i=0; i < platformW.length; i++){
        var platform = new Platform(platformW[i],20);
        platforms.push(platform);
        stage.addChild(platform);
        platform.x = platformX[i];
        platform.y = platformY[i];
    }

for(j=0; j < 5; j++){
    var crate = new Crate();
    crates.push(crate);
    stage.addChild(crate);
    resetCrates(crate);
}
key = new createjs.Bitmap(kimg);
key.x = 900;
key.y = 490;
stage.addChild(key);

Ticker.setFPS(30);
Ticker.addListener(window);
stage.update();
}

function tick() {
    heroCenter = hero.y-40;
    if (play){
        vy+=gravity;
        if (inAir){
            hero.y+=vy;
        }
        if (vy>15){
            vy=15;
        }
for(i=0; i < platforms.length; i++){
    if (hero.y >= platforms[i].y && hero.y<=(platforms[i].y+platforms[i].height) && hero.x>
    platforms[i].x && hero.x<(platforms[i].
    x+platforms[i].width)){;
    hero.y=platforms[i].y;
    vy=0;
    jumping = false;
    inAir = false;
    break;
    }else{
        inAir = true;
    }
}
for(j=0; j < crates.length; j++){
    var ct = crates[j];
    ct.y+=ct.speed;
    ct.rotation+=3;
    if (ct.y>650){
        resetCrates(ct);
    }
    if (collisionHero (ct.x, ct.y, 20)){
        gameOver();}
}
if (collisionHero (key.x+20, key.y+20,
20)){
    key.visible=false;
    door.visible=false;
}
if (collisionHero (door.x+20, door.y+40,
20) && key.visible==false){nextLevel();}
if (lfHeld){vx = -5;}
if (rtHeld){vx = 5;}

if(lfHeld && keyDn==false && inAir==false)
{
    hero.gotoAndPlay("walk_h");
    keyDn=true;
}
if(rtHeld && keyDn==false &&
inAir==false){
    hero.gotoAndPlay("walk");
    keyDn=true;
}
if (dir=="left" && keyDn==false &&
inAir==false){
    hero.gotoAndStop("idle_h");
}
if (dir=="right" && keyDn==false &&
inAir==false){
    hero.gotoAndStop("idle");
}

hero.x+=vx;
vx=vx*0.5;
if (hero.y>610){
    gameOver();
}
    }
    stage.update();
}

function end(){
    play=false;
    var l = crates.length;
    for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
        var c = crates[i];
        resetCrates(c);
    }
    hero.visible=false;
    stage.update();
}

function nextLevel(){
    gameTxt = new createjs.Text("Well Done\n\n",
"36px Arial", "#000");
 gameTxt.text += "Prepare for Level 2";
 gameTxt.textAlign = "center";
 gameTxt.x = canvas.width / 2;
 gameTxt.y = canvas.height / 4;
 stage.addChild(gameTxt);
 end();
}
function gameOver(){
    gameTxt = new createjs.Text("Game Over\n\n",
    "36px Arial", "#000");
    gameTxt.text += "Click to Play Again.";
    gameTxt.textAlign = "center";
    gameTxt.x = canvas.width / 2;
    gameTxt.y = canvas.height / 4;
    stage.addChild(gameTxt);
    end();
    canvas.onclick = handleClick;
}

function handleClick() {
    canvas.onclick = null;
    hero.visible=true;
    hero.x = 80;
    hero.y = 450;
    door.visible=true;
    key.visible=true;
    stage.removeChild(gameTxt);
    play=true;
}
function collisionHero (xPos, yPos,
Radius){
    var distX = xPos - hero.x;
    var distY = yPos - heroCenter;
    var distR = Radius + 20;
    if (distX * distX + distY * distY <=
distR * distR){
    return true;
}
}
function jump(){
    if (jumping == false && inAir == false){
        if (dir=="right"){
            hero.gotoAndStop("jump");
        }else{
            hero.gotoAndStop("jump_h");
        }
        hero.y -=20;
        vy = -25;
        jumping = true;
        keyDn=false;
    }
}
function resetCrates(crt) {
    crt.x = canvas.width * Math.random()|0;
    crt.y = 0 - Math.random()*500;
    crt.speed = (Math.random()*5)+8;
}





</script>

<title>Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">




<canvas id="canvas" width="960px" height="600px"></canvas>



</body>
</html>
```

Adding the js files as listed in the header.
Platform.js:

```
     (function(window) {
    function Platform(w,h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.initialize();
    }

Platform.prototype = new createjs.Container ();
Platform.prototype.platformBody = null;
Platform.prototype.Container_initialize = Platform.prototype.initialize;

Platform.prototype.initialize = function() {
    this.Container_initialize();
    this.platformBody = new createjs.Shape();
    this.addChild(this.platformBody);
    this.makeShape();
}

Platform.prototype.makeShape = function() {
    var g = this.platformBody.graphics;
    g.drawRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
}
window.Platform = Platform;
}(window));
```

Hero.js

```
(function(window) {
    function Hero(imgHero) {
        this.initialize(imgHero);
    }

Hero.prototype = new createjs.BitmapAnimation();
Hero.prototype.Animation_initialize = Hero.prototype.initialize;
Hero.prototype.initialize = function(imgHero) {
    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({

images: [imgHero], 
frames: {width: 60, height: 85, regX: 29, regY: 80}, animations: {
    walk: [0, 19, "walk"],
    idle: [20, 20],
    jump: [21, 21] } });

SpriteSheetUtils
.addFlippedFrames(spriteSheet, true, false, 
false);
this.Animation_initialize(spriteSheet);
this.gotoAndStop("idle");
}
window.Hero = Hero;
}(window));
```

Crate.js

```
(function(window) {
    function Crate() {
        this.initialize();
    }

Crate.prototype = new createjs.Container();
Crate.prototype.img = new Image();
Crate.prototype.Container_initialize =
Crate.prototype.initialize;
Crate.prototype.initialize = function() {

this.Container_initialize();
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("img/crate.jpg");
bmp.x=-20;
bmp.y=-20;
this.addChild(bmp);}
window.Crate = Crate;
}(window));
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you linked the tutorial, I don't see an error off hand, but I'm also not an easel whiz. Do you have an earlier version of this that works as well?

Comment: I wish I could but the tutorial is from a magazine. I'm very new to easel so was hoping I had done something very obviously wrong! My first go at it so i'm afraid I don't have an earlier version. I feel like the init() should be in a separate folder but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you try to initialize the EaselJS-objects without a namespace:

```
stage = new Stage(canvas);
```

But since 0.5.0 you have to use the createjs-namespace(or map the namespace to window before you do anything)
So what you would have to do now will ALL easelJS-classes is to add a `createjs.` before them when you are creating a new instance like this:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
```

Not sure if that's everything, but it's a start, hope this helps.

You can read more on CreateJS namepsacing here: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/README_CREATEJS_NAMESPACE.txt

Comment: Tried but still no luck! Should the background image and my other images still be loading or will nothing load if there is an error down the line?

Comment: Also editied to show the inputted "createjs" and also added the js files

Comment: Can you maybe put everything somewhere online? There must be some kind of error... and it's much easier to check for a mistake when you see it running.

Comment: I also just noticed that you use "px" inside the canvas width and height-attribute, but you can only use numbers in there, maybe everything works fine but the canvas has no height & width?

Comment: Hey again. So fixed a couple of errors, pretty sure I have it close to working but i'm now getting a "lfheld undefined" error even though I have defined it on the second script line! any thoughts?

Comment: Righto. So just updated firefox and now getting the following error: "TypeError: f.isVisible is not a function". This is in the easel library file in the first script source.

Comment: Have given up!! But thanks a mill for all the help anyway guys :-)